# VS2012: missing library package manager on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure

I am following the Azure web tutorial test-service-using-web-api and one of the steps involves the 'library package manager' tools menu item, which does not appear on my version of Visual Studios 2012.

I've looked at the other similar questions, but one relates to a 2010 version and the other one has the menu, but it doesn't work.

In my case I don't have the menu at all.

I have already taken these steps:

1. Repaired VS2012 twice
2. Followed these directions from a similar post:

   Run devenv /Resetsettings eliminate the cause of corrupted settings;
   Run devenv /ResetSkipPkgs in Command Prompt;
   Run devenv /Safemode to see if you can apply it correctly. 
   Reboot the machine into Safe Mode. This can isolate some third party application/driver's interference.

Finally I have run a log of the VS2012 startup - there is nothing strange inside it.

As a novice, it looks like my version on VS2012 doesn't have this feature!

VS2012 v11.0.606010.01, .Net framework 4.5.50709

Comment: Check that NuGet is installed: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c

Comment: Thanks - the nuGet Package Manager is installed - available from tools/add-in manager menu

Comment: Do you have the uri of the tutorial you're following? I suspect that the NuGet Package Manager is actually what you're looking for...

Comment: Its ok, i found the solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/807b3365-0172-4456-b6a4-448f2282415f/missing-the-library-package-manager-in-the-tools-menu?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is found here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/807b3365-0172-4456-b6a4-448f2282415f/missing-the-library-package-manager-in-the-tools-menu?forum=vssetup

I had to run devenv.exe /resetuserdata and select web programming on start up